# Correct way to write Pauli matrices

Tags: operators, vectors, notation

This is purely a question of notation for the Pauli matrices. What is the correct way to write them for use as operators? Would I just write the vector of the matrices as a vector i.e $$\vec{\sigma}\,,$$ or just as an operator, i.e. $$\hat{\sigma}\,,$$
or as both, i.e. $$\vec{\hat{\sigma}}$$

I've seen different ways of writing them in the literature I'm studying and just wanted to know if there was a "proper" way to write it or if it made no difference

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having both hats and arrows on top of vector-valued operators, one often indicates the 3-vector using boldface, e.g.
$$\hat{\vec{A}}~=~\hat{\bf A}, $$ 
and so forth.

Comment: Ah okay yeah that makes sense, it's slightly annoying since in the report I've been writing, it's been mostly classical mechanics so I used arrows for vectors so far but this is certainly a better notation